# fetch elements that occurred multiple times in Ruby Array

Tags: ruby

Given you have a Ruby Array like `a = [1,2,3,2,4,4,2,5]` how can you select elements that occurred multiple times in the given array ?

so return value == `[2,4]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a.group_by(&:itself).select{|_, a| a[1]}.keys
```

Comment: Although `a[1]` is shorter, I'd use the more explicit `a.length > 1`. Nice side effect: it works for `nil` and `false` values.

Comment: yep it's clearly the fastest, here are some benchmarks https://gist.github.com/equivalent/3c9a4c9d07fff79062a3

Answer (score 2):

My colleague suggested this :

```
a = [1,2,3,2,4,4,2,5]
a.select{ |el| a.count(el) > 1 }.uniq
# => [2,4]
```